# C# Compile Visual Studio Program

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I'm trying to create a program which compiles another program a bunch of times, each time adjusting some constant variables in one of the class source files (like hard coded configuration).

I need to compile the program (a c# visual studio project, if that helps at all) from within the builder. How is this done?

Comment: `each time adjusting some constant variables in one of the class source files (like hard coded configuration).` - Sounds like you'd be better off using some [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx)

Comment: You will find [many many answers on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+compile+programs&aq=f&oq=c%23+compile+programs&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j62l3.6012j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=c%23+compile+runtime&oq=c%23+compile+runtime&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30l3.11474.12493.1.12578.10.9.0.0.0.0.175.817.5j4.9.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.ayx2_0oXEXM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45512109,d.cGE&fp=d78f862414922e23&biw=1262&bih=657) if you search.  I recommend you start there and come back if you have a more specific question.

Comment: If you asked me to do somethign like this in c#, it would essentially be a glorified batch script

Comment: I know you can google, there's a meta question in fact in which it is stated that SO should ideally be the first result for such a question however. This specifically feels like a question which numerous others may have - although like with most things you can always find an answer somewhere, it would be best to have a clear answer.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to compile the other program repeatedly, and can't just call a function with those parameters and let the VM handle optimizing? With basic opts like memoization (if appropriate) and currying/prepped functors containing anonymous functions, you might be able to get some decent performance out of the VM. That is assuming your compilation is about performance.

Comment: Peachy please read my comment on another answer where the same question is asked.

Comment: MSBuild is used to compile C# projects. But I'm not exactly sure what you are asking so voting to close. Clarification if you actually asking any of following questions would be useful: how to run MSBuild from C# program, how to replace value in a text (.CS) file, how to copy files around?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It's clearly titled "Compile Visual Studio Program" - and I mention doing it from within source. Closing would be pointless since there's a answer already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make calls to the C# compiler in a variety of ways:

- You can use the [command-line compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx) to compile a specific C# file to an executable.
- You can compile c# strings using [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655?wa=wsignin1.0).
- If you want to compile a Visual Studio project, you can use [`MSBuild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd393574.aspx).
- The [Mono Compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) can also compile c# code.

However, what you're doing sounds like the wrong solution to a problem. It makes more sense to have that be a variable and provide it via command line args, app settings, or downloaded from an authenticated web server.

Comment: The advantage to this is then obfuscation of the executable is done - is there a way to change a configuration variable specific to that compiled product without recompiling?

Comment: You could use application settings. The problem here is, if you're trying to obfuscate your code, giving people multiple versions with a small known difference will actually make it easier to crack. If this is a copy-protection thing, I think the industry has decided that trying to hide the code is a waste of time in general. These days we do things like make people register - "you can't use this without a Facebook account" is pretty good copy protection. Then you put all the data on the server, linked to that Facebook account, so a copy of the executable is useless by itself.

Comment: There is no problem if people crack changing the value. The idea is merely to have a specific constant for each exe compiled.

Comment: And what exactly is that constant that makes it so important?  Can't you just put it in the app config (as Jasmine suggested) and encrypt?

Comment: Since all of the code except that constant will be the same between different copies, that can help you understand the obfuscated code. You know that "thing that changed" in each file is the constant, you can see where it is, and that gives you a good hook to start understanding the code. Like I said, preventing someone from decompiling and understanding your code is a waste of time. Make your code useless to anyone who isn't registered, and nobody will bother to crack it. We tried encrypting our app, but then people just shared the password. Since we created accounts, nobody pirates any more

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the question. The question was how to trigger a c# build from code.

Comment: I answered that already, but these comments uncovered that what you're trying to do won't accomplish what you think it will, so I'm telling you about other options. Compiling different versions of your program won't prevent people from copying it and could potentially make it easier to crack. You stated that was the reason why you're doing this, and I don't want people to steal your stuff! Personally I think you're asking the wrong question here - if what you really want is to protect your code.

Comment: @Jasmine I've accepted and cleaned up your answer to supply just information rather than a question to the OP. In the future, although it's very helpful to supply related information, I recommend you clarify what the question is before supplying so much additional information through comments. The title is `C# Compile Visual Studio Program` not `How to secure programs`.

Comment: @Jasmine I think your approach to answering this question will be valuable other people in the future who are asking the same question, so I've edited your question back in (but reworded as a statement) in case people don't get to the comments.

Comment: Oh thanks, it looks way better now. I've been on this site a while but I admit I haven't really learned the format yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the .net compiler using `Process.Start`

The executable is called csc.exe and is usually located in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.X.XXX

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The sample I copy/pasted was not a correct one. The option I was looking to offer is using [CompileAssemblyFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromfile.aspx). Sample code cold be obtained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.aspx)

Comment: That code doesn't compile anything. It outputs the source code.

Comment: @Jasmine yes, I realized that after I submitted

Comment: LOL, I've done that before. Posted a link that was totally like, a photo of an airplane or something, when I meant to link to docs.